# Accessing quizzes and turnitin.com dropboxes with valence

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am trying to collect some information on the usage of quizzes and turnitin.com enabled dropboxes for specific courses within the d2l database. All I really need is a way to tell via valence whether or not a course offering has a turnitin.com enabled dropbox and/or a quiz associated with it, though other useful information would be nice as well. Is there a way to do this with valence? I should note that I am aware of how to access a list of standard dropboxes, but I cannot seem to find how to tell if that particular dropbox is turnitin.com enabled. I have no starting point for quizzes. I appreciate your help, and please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current way to identify, through Valence, a TurnItIn enabled Dropbox. Our TurnItIn integration is an extension available to customers who have the appropriate TurnItIn licensing. Because we cannot assume it is in place, we cannot expose this data through Valence. I am not sure if this information would be available through TurnItIn API's.

In regards to Quizzes, today we don't have Quiz data exposed through Valence. One option for you, which isn't perfect, would be to parse through Content Topics looking for Quicklinks which contain a reference type of quiz. This would provide you with a list of how many quizzes are linked into the course's content experience.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately for me, that effectively puts a halt to my current plan, but at least this gives me a concrete answer.